# Get extended properties in office 365 graph delta API

Tags: odata, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We are building an application that integrates office 365 using graph APIs. We need to pull all the office 365 contacts into our system and needs to be in sync.
There is [delta](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/known_issues.md#extensions) API in office to pull only delta changes. We found an issue like we can not pull extended properties(Which includes outlook MPAI fields like mobile phone, assistant phone, etc)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/delta
```

So office 365 expects the client to make extra API call to get extended properties for each contact?
Means if the user has 1000 contacts, the client has to make 1000 plus API calls to pull the contacts from office365?

There is another contact search API which supports extended properties in a single call. Can we use this to pull the delta changes?

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt  '2018-07-28T05:25:32Z'
```

Please advice us how we can effectively pull office365 contacts

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As far as i can see (and observed myself with calendar events) expand is not supported for most delta query calls. See [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview) for delta query under Optional Query Parameters:

> `$expand` is only suported for the `manager` and `members` navigational property for users and groups respectively.

Your filter request is also not supported for delta query. If u use :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/delta?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt  2018-07-28T05:25:32Z
```

You get the following error:

```
"error":
{
    "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQuery",
    "message": "The following parameters are not supported with change tracking over the 'Contacts' resource: '$orderby, $filter, $select, $expand, $search, $top'.",
    "innerError":
    {
        "request-id": "da1174b3-d...",
        "date": "2018-08-06T12:45:34"
    }
}
```

Funnily enough select is actually supported ([contact delta doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/contact_delta)).
Any way it seems like your only choice is to expand the normal contact request for a user. 
If there are a lot of changes, you could try [batching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching) the expanded contact requests.

Comment: Actually getting the extended properties with last modified date filter.


https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge 2018-07-28T05:25:32Z&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x3A1E' or id eq 'String 0x3A1F' or id eq 'String 0x3A21' or id eq 'String 0x3A24' or id eq 'String 0x3A25' or id eq 'String 0x3A23' or id eq 'String 0x3A2E' or id eq 'String 0x3A02' or id eq 'String 0x3A1D' or id eq 'String 0x3A2C' or id eq 'String 0x3A4B')

Comment: @RamarajKaruppusamy Correct you need the expand to get the singleValueExtendedProperties. I just wanted to point out that the url you provided in your question `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt  '2018-07-28T05:25:32Z`
" is not supported if you combine it with delta query. The first part of my answer (the fact that `$expand` is not supported with delta query for contacts) is probably more relevant for you.